# Compare files block by block (bytes) java

Tags: java, compare, arrays, block, mappedbytebuffer

I try to compare two files block by block. If blocks are equals - get next block and compare them.
If final blocks are equals - return true; all other variant - return false.
I don't understand how to get right the next block  and how to get the end of file.

```
private static boolean getBlocks(File file1, File file2, int count) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile raf1 = new RandomAccessFile(file1, "r");
    RandomAccessFile raf2 = new RandomAccessFile(file2, "r");
    int point = count * 512;
    FileChannel fc1 = raf1.getChannel();
    FileChannel fc2 = raf2.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer buffer1 = fc1.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, point, 512);
    MappedByteBuffer buffer2 = fc2.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, point, 512);
    byte[] bytes1 = new byte[512];
    byte[] bytes2 = new byte[512];
    buffer1.get(bytes1);
    buffer2.get(bytes2);
    if (bytes1.length == bytes2.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes1.length; i++) {
            if(bytes1[i] != bytes2[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (true) {
            count++;
            getBlocks(file1, file2, point);
        }
    }
    buffer1.clear();
    buffer2.clear();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can read a file byte by byte until EOF is reached: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Testingforendoffilewhilereadingabyteatatime.htm

When using `MappedByteBuffer` this should be the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12509314/1321564